# How to hide grid lines in VS2010 XAML preview?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

Visual Studio 2010 shows some faint grid lines over the control rendering in the XAML Designer view.  How do I make them go away?

[image: screenshot of the undesired gridlines]

Comment: Stop using the designer view...